# Drag and Drop with multiple drop locations Jquery, Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, drag-and-drop

I am trying to manipulate the source file from the Jquery user interface samples for a 'simple photo manager' example. (http://jqueryui.com/droppable/#photo-manager) 
I would like to create multiple gallery options so that the photos can be dragged and dropped into multiple, separate gallery with the same function as the individual trash bin from the example. When I create a new $trash.droppable() and label it separately as trash1 the script still will only allow the elements to be moved into one gallery, even though both are highlighted upon dragging the element.. it will not differentiate between trash and trash1.

Here's what I have so far: http://superdigital2.com/users/sackett-greg/Java-Test/untitled.html

```
$trash.droppable({
  accept: "#gallery > li",
  activeClass: "ui-state-highlight",
  drop: function( event, ui ) {
    deleteImage( ui.draggable );
  }
});

$trash1.droppable({
  accept: "#gallery > li",
  activeClass: "ui-state-highlight",
  drop: function( event, ui ) {
    deleteImage( ui.draggable );
  }
});
```